# Why does a POST request not work with a trailing slash, but a GET request does?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I was trying to an AJAX post request to a specific route, it returned a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`for seemingly no reason.

My ajax request:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/delete-photo/',
        type: 'post',
        data: { 
            id: someId
        },
        success: function(xhr)
        {
                    ...
       }
    });
```

My route:

```
    Route::post('admin/delete-photo','PhotoController@deletePhoto');
```

If I changed it to a GET request it worked, but not POST.

As @Moppo said in his comment, removing the trailing slash, changing my AJAX request url to `url: '/admin/delete-photo'` worked.

But why did the trailing slash prevent the POST request, but still worked with a GET?

Is this specific to Laravel or would the same apply to any AJAX request?

Comment: try changing `url: '/admin/delete-photo/'` to `url: '/admin/delete-photo'`

Comment: ... that worked! Thanks, I really was overthinking it.

Comment: Any ideas why the trailing slash would prevent a POST request from working but not a GET?